# MVC controller parameters always null

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

my ajax code

```
function gonder() {
    var params = {
        DonationInfo: {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            lastname: $('#lastname').val(),
            phone: $('#phone').val(),
            type: $('#type').val(),
            amounth: $('#amounth').val(),
            quentity: $('#quentity').val()
        }
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Benafactor")',
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.success);
            $('#target').html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

MY Controller

```
   [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index([FromBody] Mymodel data)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true });

    }
```

also i tried with string

and here is Mymodel

```
  public class Mymodel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string amounth { get; set; }
    public string quentity { get; set; }
}
```

i tried hard , looked for the all same question but nothing work for me please help i can see the data in request payload but can't get the parameters into controller

Comment: use jquery post check this link https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: Even easier than the answers, Remove `contentType` option and use `data: $('form').serialize(),` (.serialize()` correctly serializes your form controls to json)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you serialize object(`params)` as json then the structure of the mvc `ActionResult` paramter model(`Mymodel`) and the object(`params)` need to be same structure, in your code `params` and `Mymodel` is not same structure. Make it same will solve the problem

```
var params = {
            name: $('#name').val(),
            lastname: $('#lastname').val(),
            phone: $('#phone').val(),
            type: $('#type').val(),
            amounth: $('#amounth').val(),
            quentity: $('#quentity').val()
       };
```

Comment: i will but have to wait for 8 minutes

Comment: better solution is given below

Comment: you are wellcome, happy coding :)

Comment: I think, to add impact, it would be beneficial to give an explanation as to what was wrong, rather than just giving the answer.

Answer (score 1):

use this :

```
var params = {
        name: $('#name').val(),
        lastname: $('#lastname').val(),
        phone: $('#phone').val(),
        type: $('#type').val(),
        amounth: $('#amounth').val(),
        quentity: $('#quentity').val()
    }
```

for a complex object, its better to use variables than including it in ajax method

Answer (score 0):

JSON.stringify is not necessary`data: params.DonationInfo`

Answer (score 0):

```
function gonder() {
    var data= {

            name: $('#name').val(),
            lastname: $('#lastname').val(),
            phone: $('#phone').val(),
            type: $('#type').val(),
            amounth: $('#amounth').val(),
            quentity: $('#quentity').val()

    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Benafactor")',
        type: 'POST',
        async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify(params),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.success);
            $('#target').html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

Your controller will look like this

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Mymodel data)
    {
        return Json(new { success = true });

    }
```